# Why are these throw dice results so even?

Tags: c++

This is supposed to roll 6 dice, and keep a record of how many are unique. E.g: 1 2 3 4 5 6 = 6 unique numbers, 1 1 1 1 1 1 = 1 unique number, 1 2 3 3 3 3 = 3 unique numbers. I keep getting a very even % for each dice thrown, about 16.7%.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int numberGenerator()
{
int x = (rand() % 6) + 1;
return x;
}

int diceCounter()
{

int counter[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    int k = numberGenerator();
        if (k == 1)
           counter[0] = 1;
        if (k == 2)
           counter[1] = 1;
        if (k == 3)
           counter[2] = 1;
        if (k == 4)
           counter[3] = 1;
        if (k == 5)
           counter[4] = 1;
        if (k == 6)
           counter[5] = 1;
     }
return counter[0]+counter[1]+counter[2]+counter[3]+counter[4]+counter[5];
}                 // returns how many unique numbers were rolled


int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
cout << diceCounter() << endl;

int a1 = 0;
int a2 = 0;
int a3 = 0;
int a4 = 0;
int a5 = 0;
int a6 = 0;
int p;


for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
{
p = numberGenerator();        // for number of unique numbers, it adds +1 to counter
if (p == 1)
a1 += 1;
if (p == 2)
a2 += 1;
if (p == 3)
a3 += 1;
if (p == 4)
a4 += 1;
if (p == 5)
a5 += 1;
if (p == 6)
a6 += 1;
}
cout << "1 ==> " << (a1 / 1000000.0)*100 << "%" << endl;
cout << "2 ==> " << (a2 / 1000000.0)*100 << "%" << endl;
cout << "3 ==> " << (a3 / 1000000.0)*100 << "%" << endl;
cout << "4 ==> " << (a4 / 1000000.0)*100 << "%" << endl;
cout << "5 ==> " << (a5 / 1000000.0)*100 << "%" << endl;
cout << "6 ==> " << (a6 / 1000000.0)*100 << "%" << endl;

                // this results in uniform 16.7% percentages
}
```

Comment: Law of large numbers?

Comment: But it's supposed to be a much lower % for 1 or 6 unique numbers as opposed to 3 or 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your loop, you're calling `numberGenerator` rather than `diceCounter`.

So instead of counting the number of unique results from rolling 6 dice, you're getting counts of each number for a single roll. And as you'd expect each number is coming out 1/6 of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @MichaelAnderson's answer:

Random numbers are all actually pseudo-random.

They work on `seed` values. So each time you call `rand()`, call `srand()` before that to reseed the random number generator:
Like so:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand();
```

Comment: You only need to do this once at the beginning of the program, and only if you want each run of the program to produce a different random sequence. If you do it before each `rand()` call, and your loop takes less than 1 second, you'll get the same random number each time.

Comment: If you look at the first line of main, it has a seed call (`srand`) in it - that was the first thing I looked for...

Comment: Well it doesn't hurt to reseed - I guess @MichaelAnderson

Comment: Actually as @Barmar pointed out, reseeding each rand call is _very_ bad - (a) its expensive, (b) if your loop takes <1 sec then you'll reseed using the same value, meaning loss of randomness rather than better randomness. I was actually looking for failure to seed each time.